# Specific NTFS/Share permissions

Tags: windows, ntfs, windows-server-2012-r2, shared-folders

Having a bit of a struggle with some folder permissions I've been asked to create.  I'm sure they're fairly simple to create, but I'm aboard the struggle bus.

I've created security groups for each subfolder of the directory.  There's an overall security group that allows everyone in the company to see the folder. Someone funky is happening when assigning permissions to the subfolders. When I remove the "Everyone" group, it removes my ability to see the subfolder.

**IDEA:**

- **Top Level Directory** - Everyone can see
- - **Directory 1** - Everyone (can see folder but not contents) | Group 1 - (Read/Write/Execute)
- - **Directory 2** - Everyone ( can see folder but not contents) | Group 2 - (Read/Write/Execute)
- - **Directory 3** - Everyone ( can see folder but not contents) | Group 3 - (Read/Write/Execute)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks that can help you

- look for which group gives you acces rights and you answer by yourself to your question.
- You must distinguish to 2 types of security groups:

  - ***Groups to access resources***. Typically  R/Exec and a RW group on each resource (here managed directory). Never grant Full Control to user, never, no never
  - ***Managing Groups***. Must be present everywhere with Full Control Acccess.

If you are admin, you must be member of one or more managing group. i.e. ServiceDesk Group, Admin Server, Admin Workstation Group, Domain Admins (yep ! All admins should not be members of this group)

- **And what about Access rights for the share ?** Never Minds, don't play with this. Everyone Full Control or more secure, Domain Users or Authenticated users Full control. You can put AD Groups if you want, but after that it really difficult (and sometimes impossible) to manage.

  > Keep in mind : between rights on sharing and NTFS permissions, **the smallest is the winner.** 
  >   i.e. : 
  >   Access Rights on Share - NTFS Permissions- result
  >   Read - Full Control - Read
  >   normal when you think about it, you must pass through the share before access to files.

If you want to audit/Manage quickly the NTFS permissions : Use the module NTFSSecurity (in powershell Gallery)

A example of use with some few lines of code : 
$share = "\server\share"
    # gather first level directories. If multi-level use -Depth
    $Tree = Get-ChildItem -Path $share  -Directory | Select-Object Name, FullName
    # Import Module NTFSSecurity (most pleasant to use that Get-Acl cmdlet)
    Import-Module NTFSSecurity
    # Gather NTFS permissions for the share
    $result = Get-NTFSAccess -Path $share
    # Gather NTFS permissions for each subdir. 
    $result += foreach ($dir in $Tree)
    {
    Get-NTFSAccess -Path dir.fullName -ExcludeInherited # just to lighten the output file. You can also -ExcludeExplicit depending of that you're looking for. 
    }
    # Export in a .csv file
    $result | Export-Csv -Path c:\exportPath\NTFSPerms.csv -NoTypeInformation 
    # use -Encoding -Delimiter if necessary

Nota : do not consider this as a script, there is no error handling. It's just some lines, nothing more.

Regards
Oliv